# Avalanche of dependency problems and insserv errors

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and a dist-upgrade failed with dependency problems. I tried to fix it with sudo dpkg --configure -a and that seems to have made everything much worse - I get the error I've copied below. I've now no idea what to do - any suggestions much appreciated!

Dan

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu11) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'K16mdns' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mdns' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service mdns if started
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service mdns and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up lightdm (1.18.3-0ubuntu1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K16mdns' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mdns' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service mdns if started
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service mdns and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting mdns depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools-core:
 initramfs-tools-core depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.3); however:
  Package initramfs-tools-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic:
 linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic depends on initramfs-tools | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.43.45); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 lightdm
 initramfs-tools-core
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 xserver-xorg-core
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer you generally: when you see such a deadlock you can try a few things, all of them may possibly cause you problems, so you should probably use them only temporarily.

1) *Try to remove offending packages*. In your case it's mdns and plymouth. I don't know mdns (if nobody depends on it you may be lucky to remove it, but you may lose some functionality, so reinstall it later); by removing plymouth you would lose boot animation and stuff, you may not want to do it.

2) *try to check the /etc/init.d/ files and try to remove "$all" from dependencies (the commented block on the top of the file), especially from Required-* lines.* In this case I'd check /etc/init.d/mdns and remove "$all" from the beginning part. It will cause mdns start later, which - by educated guess - should not break your system (but it may with pretty low probability, still no guarantees). Generally "$all" is not justified and may be a packaging bug. Possibly upgrade even fixes it for you.

You can test it by running "insserv -n" manually.

Comment: Thank you! 

I've removed mdns and that's removed the deadlock. I still get the series of dependency errors, and sudo dpkg --configure -a doesn't seem to fix them. 

Any further ideas would be fantastic

Comment: OK - this is now fixed. The dependency errors started with 'invoke-rc.d: dangling symlink: /etc/rcS.d/S03udev'. That symlink pointed to etc/init.d/udev, which didn't exist. So I deleted the symlink and now all seems fine

Please don't tell me I've made a terrible mistake that will come back and bite me!